# How to use explicit addressing in IBM (HLASM)

Tags: assembly, mainframe, zos, addressing-mode, s390x

I’ve been looking for information about explicit addressing, online but there is nothing and there is, the explanations are pretty vague. I hope someone can explain me with details and if possible witn example.
I would like to know, what registers should be used as index, base, and what should be the displacement value

Example 8(,4) or 5(0,5) or 6(7)

Comment: You sort of learn the "language" if you say it aloud...most times, the registers are inside the parens, sometimes also with a length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can depend on the instruction being executed.  Please see this reference from IBM to help sort through the details.  Being an old Z performance person when people ask a question about performance the answer is almost always, “It depends”

See this [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.asma400/asmr1021113.htm)

> Registers that are not explicitly coded in symbolic assembler language
>   representation of machine instructions, but are nevertheless used by
>   assembled machine instructions, are divided into two categories: Base
>   registers that are implicit in the symbolic addresses specified. (See
>   Addresses.) The registers can be identified by examining the object
>   code or the USING instructions that assign base registers for the
>   source module.
>
> Registers that are used by machine instructions, but do
>   not appear in assembled object code. 
>   For double shift and fullword multiply and divide instructions, the odd-numbered register, whose number is one greater than the even-numbered register specified as the first operand.
>
> For Move Long and Compare Logical Long instructions,
>   the odd-numbered registers, whose number is one greater than
>   even-numbered registers specified in the two operands.
>
> For Branch on Index High (BXH) and the Branch on Index Low or Equal (BXLE)
>   instructions, if the register specified for the second operand is an
>   even-numbered register, the next higher odd-numbered register is used
>   to contain the value to be used for comparison.
>
> For Load Multiple (LM, LAM) and Store Multiple (STM, STAM) instructions, the registers that lie between the registers specified in the first two operands.
>
> For extended-precision floating point instructions, the second register of
>   the register pair.
>
> For Compare and Form Codeword (CFC) instruction, registers 1, 2, and 3 are used. >
>   For Translate and Test (TRT) instruction, registers 1 and 2 are used. For Update Tree (UPT) instruction, registers 0-5 are used.
>
> For Edit and Mark (EDMK) instruction, register 1 is used. For certain control instructions, one or more of registers 0-4 and register 14 are used. See "Control
>   Instructions" in the applicable z/Architecture Principles of Operation
>   manual.
>
> For certain input and output instructions, either or both registers 1 and 2 are used. See "Input/Output Instructions" in the applicable z/Architecture Principles of Operation manual. 
>   On a processor with a vector facility:
>
> 1. For instructions that manipulate long floating-point data in vector registers, the odd-numbered vector
>      registers, whose number is one greater than the even-numbered vector
>      registers specified in each operand.
> 2. For instructions that manipulate
>      64 bit signed binary data in vector registers, the odd-numbered vector
>      registers, whose number is one greater than the even-numbered vector
>      registers specified in each operand.